# WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged doesn't fire

Tags: c#, .net, download, webclient

Doing some programming in Visual Studio with C# and I'm trying to download a file and link the progress to a `ProgressBar`. It worked perfectly fine when I did it in Visual Basic, but when I tried to do it in C#, the `Client.DownloadProgressChanged` event just doesn't fire.

```
System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient();
Client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged;
Client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), filepath + filename);
while (Client.IsBusy) { }
```

The only thing in `Client_DownloadProgressChanged` is some code that changes the value of a `TextBox` to "Test1" which I did just to see if it runs.

Comment: Under what context does this code run? If it's on the UI thread, `while (Client.IsBusy)` will block.

Comment: I have no idea how to do anything relating to threading, so there's no mention of it in my code. Whatever it does by default is what thread is being used.

Comment: @wgraham DownloadFileAsync will run on a thread within the threadpool, not on the UI thread, so it's OK.  DownloadFileAsync also prints [network tracing information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyb3xww8(v=vs.110).aspx) info so you might want to look to see what's going on in the background.

Comment: @JNYRanger - It's trying to update a UI element, it has to be invoked on the UI thread.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I know.  `DownloadFileAsync` runs on the threadpool.  The event delegate runs on the UI thread.  These are the defaults, and  based on what OP stated he hasn't modified them.  I was not providing an answer to why it isn't working, just a suggestion to take a look at the tracing to see what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: He's locking the thread with his while loop

Comment: @JNYRanger, @YuvalItzchakov is absolutely right. While the work that `DownloadFileAsync` is done on the thread pool (unless a different task scheduler is used), he's still waiting for it to finish in the UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
while (Client.IsBusy) { }
```

Ties up the UI message loop. It keeps it consumed and doesn't allow any other messages to be processed. Meanwhile, the event is being queued on the UI thread, which is blocked.

If you comment that line and the download completes, you'll see you textbox update properly.

You should re-think what you're trying to do. If `Client`, consider moving the while loop to a [*background thread*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)